# How I can find my .RDA has been loaded to R

Tags: r

I have a scenario where I want to check If R has loaded the .RDA(which is a model)
I want this for getting prediction call as I don`t want to load every time I am asking for a prediction.

I tried with this below code

```
  if(!is.na(T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda)){
  print("started")
  bar<-load(file = "C:\\T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda")
  print("ended ")
}
```

Result I get is

```
Error: object 'T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda' not found
```

Comment: R does not regard the file name once a rda file is loaded. Instead the name  of your model or data is stored in the rda itself. If you use RStudio (which I highly recommend) you should see something new in the Environment window. If you know the name of your model you should be able to check using `exists("T2I_Vendor_Eval1")`

Comment: I think this needs a larger snippet - and information on the content of the file. Currently the code snippet fails because it lacks the *variable* `T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda` (not the file!).  Maybe you can clarify. Also why is this tagged java?

Comment: thanks -JonGrub You solved my prob, I used the studio and find out my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
 if(!is.na(T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda)){
  print("started")
  bar<-load(file = "C:\\T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda")
  print("ended end")
}
```

I did this

```
if(!exists("T2I_Vendor_Eval1")){
  print("started")
  load(file = "C:\\T2I_Vendor_Eval1.rda")
  print("ended end")
}
```

It worked for me.
thanks for you help **@JonGrub**

Comment: `exists` needs a string argument. You need `exists("T2I_Vendor_Eval1")` unless that object is a string itself.

Comment: thanks pointing me out, missed the ". I have edited my answer